# Adding a Sub Menu Options Page WP Backend Menu. Whats wrong with my code?

Tags: php, theme-development

Hello I'm currently following a guide on how to add input to my created Sub Menu Pages. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsyVR.jpg) is a pic of what is showing up.When I view the sub-menu page.

No Errors, just not showing the text field. The Function function `mytheme_general_name()` is not getting called in the 2nd `add_submenu_page`, but I don't see what is wrong with it.

I copied the Here is my Current two php files in use

File Name: `function-admin.php`

```
/*

@package Jeron

    ========================
        ADMIN PAGE
    ========================
*/

function mytheme_add_theme_options() {
    // Generate Theme Options Page
    add_menu_page('My Themes Theme Options', 'Theme Options', 'manage_options', 'theme2_options', 'mytheme_create_page', get_template_directory_uri().'/img/themeoptionsicon.png', 110);

    // Generate Theme Options Sub Pages
    add_submenu_page('theme2_options', 'Theme Options', 'General', 'manage_options', 'theme2_options', 'mytheme_create_page');
    add_submenu_page('theme2_options', 'Typography', 'Typography', 'manage_options', 'theme_options_typography', 'mytheme_create_typography_page');
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_theme_options');

// Activate Custom Settings
add_action('admin_init', 'mytheme_custom_settings');

function mytheme_custom_settings() {
    register_setting('mytheme-settings-group', 'first_name');
    add_settings_section('mytheme-general-options', 'General Settings', 'mytheme_general_options', 'theme2_options');
    add_settings_field('general-name', 'First Name', 'mytheme_general_name', 'theme2_options', 'mytheme_settings_group');
}

function mytheme_general_options() {
    echo 'Customize Your Theme Options Below';
}

function mytheme_general_name() {
    $firstName = esc_attr(get_option('first_name'));
    echo '<input type="text" name="first_name" value="'.$firstName.'" placeholder="First Name" />';
}

function mytheme_create_page() {
    require_once(get_template_directory().'/inc/templates/mytheme-admin.php');
}

function mytheme_create_typography_page() {
    echo '<h1>My Theme Typography</h1>';
}

?>
```

File Name: `mytheme-admin.php`

```
<h1>My Theme Options</h1>
<?php settings_errors(); ?>
<form method="post" action="options.php">
    <?php settings_fields('mytheme_settings_group');?>
    <?php do_settings_sections( 'theme2_options' ); ?>
    <?php submit_button(); ?>
</form>
```

Comment: there is a opening php tag sorry about that.

Comment: Also here is the correct code I'm suppose to be following, I've looked/compared and I can't find what is wrong github.com/Alecaddd/Sunset-theme

Answer (score -1):

Replaced mytheme_settings_group with mytheme-general-options, I thought this was the section id, not a unique id. Thanks for everyones time who reads this. Hopefully it helps someone else.